# SQL CLR errors after the July 2020 update

Tags: .net, sql-server, webclient, sqlclr

I have a large system that uses a SQL CLR component to contact a server and get XML back. It's been rock-solid until the latest update. Now instead of getting XML in it throws an error: The type initializer for 'Scope' threw an exception. If I remove the update, it works normally. Any clue what in that big roll-up might have broken SQL CLR using WebClient to get XML?

Here is a snippet from a test program that basically is the same as the really large module:

```
Try
    Dim values As New NameValueCollection
    Dim enc As Encoding = New UTF8Encoding(True, True)
    values.Add("Username", "xxx")
    values.Add("Password", "yyy")
    values.Add("App", "test")
    values.Add("InputData", Uri.EscapeDataString(strInputData))

    Dim strResponse As String = ""
    Dim strURL As String = server & "/service/amps_price.aspx"

    Using client As New WebClient()
    Dim responseBytes As Byte() = client.UploadValues(strURL, values)
    strResponse = (New System.Text.UTF8Encoding(False)).GetString(responseBytes)
    End Using

    Dim xmlResponse As New XmlDocument()
    xmlResponse.LoadXml(strResponse)
    Dim blnValidResponse As Boolean

    blnValidResponse = Integer.TryParse(xmlResponse.SelectSingleNode("Amps/ReturnCode").InnerText, intAmpsReturnCode)
    strAmpsReturnDesc = xmlResponse.SelectSingleNode("Amps/ReturnDesc").InnerText

    If (blnValidResponse) Then
    strApcPricerResults = strResponse
    End If

    intAmpsReturnCode = -99
    strAmpsReturnDesc = "ERROR"

Catch ex As WebException
    intAmpsReturnCode = ex.Status
    strAmpsReturnDesc = ex.Message
End Try
```

Edit: Add stack trace:

```
The type initializer for 'Scope' threw an exception. -    at System.Data.TypeLimiter.Scope.IsTypeUnconditionallyAllowed(Type type)
   at System.Data.TypeLimiter.Scope.IsAllowedType(Type type)
   at System.Data.TypeLimiter.EnsureTypeIsAllowed(Type type, TypeLimiter capturedLimiter)
   at System.Data.DataColumn.UpdateColumnType(Type type, StorageType typeCode)
   at System.Data.DataColumn..ctor(String columnName, Type dataType, String expr, MappingType type)
   at System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleElementColumn(XmlSchemaElement elem, DataTable table, Boolean isBase)
   at System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleParticle(XmlSchemaParticle pt, DataTable table, ArrayList tableChildren, Boolean isBase)
   at System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleComplexType(XmlSchemaComplexType ct, DataTable table, ArrayList tableChildren, Boolean isNillable)
   at System.Data.XSDSchema.InstantiateTable(XmlSchemaElement node, XmlSchemaComplexType typeNode, Boolean isRef)
   at System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleTable(XmlSchemaElement node)
   at System.Data.XSDSchema.LoadSchema(XmlSchemaSet schemaSet, DataSet ds)
   at System.Data.DataSet.InferSchema(XmlDocument xdoc, String[] excludedNamespaces, XmlReadMode mode)
   at System.Data.DataSet.ReadXml(XmlReader reader, XmlReadMode mode, Boolean denyResolving)
   at Amps.Pcm.clsOutptData.UpdateApc(SqlConnection conn, Int32 intClaimId, Decimal decPaymentPercent, String xmlResults)
   at Amps.Pcm.StoredProcedures.usp_adj_clr_api_outpatient_price(SqlInt32 claim_id, SqlInt32 contract_id, SqlString vch_server, SqlInt32 int_port)
```

Comment: Sounds like your CLR component contains a class named `Scope` and it has a static constructor. You will need to investigate what that constructor is attempting to do and what exception it it throwing.

Comment: I do not have a Scope class, but I have seen that term used in SQL CLR documentation. It is likely some basic internal class used by the CLR system.

Comment: When you say "until the latest update", what update is that? What happens if you run the code outside of SQL Server?

Comment: In addition to testing outside of SQL Server as @NielsBerglund suggested (a console app, perhaps), have you rebooted the server upon applying the update? or at least restarted the SQL Server instance? And did you mean this update: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-july-2020-cumulative-update-preview-for-windows-10-version-2004/ ? It does mention touching "Net Libraries" to "Addresses a memory leak in HttpListener". It is possible that something got messed up, in which case you should report the problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete error message with stack trace as that will contain important information relevant to your issue, such as `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.`

Comment: The code snippet runs outside of SQL, and works fine. It is not possible to run the actual code outside of SQL as it is a part of a much larger system.

Comment: This is the update for Server 2016 that caused the failure: July 14, 2020—KB4565511 I can't get a finer-resolved update KBnumber other than the roll-up.

Comment: The KB causing the issue is KB4565635.  If you uninstall it, it should resume functioning normally (as a short term fix only).  Will take some SQLCLR code changes to address properly.

Comment: Here is a Microsoft article about the solution that @KevinFrancis cites: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4576575/execution-of-sql-server-clr-fails-with-typeinitializationexception

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the issue for me was the installation of KB4565635 AND/OR KB4565588.  Uninstalling this patch allowed my SQLCLR routine to function properly.  I'll be making code changes to address permanently.  I'll include more details after the permanent fix. Again, never a good idea to exclude a KB patch permanently, so this is a short term fix for me.

EDIT: I've found that every SQLCLR function or stored procedure that contains XML was affected.  I was able to fix by adding the following line as the first line in each SQLCLR object that contained XML functionality...

AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Data.AllowArbitraryDataSetTypeInstantiation", true);

For example...
[SqlFunction(Name = "Event", FillRowMethodName = "EventFill",
TableDefinition = "OccurredTime datetime, AckTime datetime, ClosedTime datetime, Category smallint, State smallint, Priority smallint, Type smallint, EventDescription nvarchar(256), EventDetail xml",
DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]

public static IEnumerable EventInit(SqlInt32 sourceDeviceId, SqlDateTime startDate, SqlDateTime endDate)
{
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Data.AllowArbitraryDataSetTypeInstantiation", true);

The error message that appears when this issue appears looks as follows...

```
Error on SourceDeviceAttributeId : 4
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure RefreshWarehouse, Line 223

Message: SDAID 4: Error 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure RefreshAggregateData, Line 216, A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "Trend": 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Scope' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
   at System.Data.TypeLimiter.Scope..cctor()
System.TypeInitializationException: 
   at Eaton.FRSCoreDB.Database.UserDefinedFunctions.TrendInit(SqlInt32 sourceDeviceAttributeId, SqlDateTime startDate, SqlDateTime endDate, SqlInt32 maxRows)
```

OR....

The type initializer for 'Scope' threw an exception. -    at System.Data.TypeLimiter.Scope.IsTypeUnconditionallyAllowed(Type type)
at System.Data.TypeLimiter.Scope.IsAllowedType(Type type)
at System.Data.TypeLimiter.EnsureTypeIsAllowed(Type type, TypeLimiter capturedLimiter)
at System.Data.DataColumn.UpdateColumnType(Type type, StorageType typeCode)
at System.Data.DataColumn..ctor(String columnName, Type dataType, String expr, MappingType type)
at System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleElementColumn(XmlSchemaElement elem, DataTable table, Boolean isBase)
at System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleParticle(XmlSchemaParticle pt, DataTable table, ArrayList tableChildren, Boolean isBase)
at System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleComplexType(XmlSchemaComplexType ct, DataTable table, ArrayList tableChildren, Boolean isNillable)
at System.Data.XSDSchema.InstantiateTable(XmlSchemaElement node, XmlSchemaComplexType typeNode, Boolean isRef)
at System.Data.XSDSchema.HandleTable(XmlSchemaElement node)
at System.Data.XSDSchema.LoadSchema(XmlSchemaSet schemaSet, DataSet ds)
at System.Data.DataSet.InferSchema(XmlDocument xdoc, String[] excludedNamespaces, XmlReadMode mode)
at System.Data.DataSet.ReadXml(XmlReader reader, XmlReadMode mode, Boolean denyResolving)
at Amps.Pcm.clsOutptData.UpdateApc(SqlConnection conn, Int32 intClaimId, Decimal decPaymentPercent, String xmlResults)
at Amps.Pcm.StoredProcedures.usp_adj_clr_api_outpatient_price(SqlInt32 claim_id, SqlInt32 contract_id, SqlString vch_server, SqlInt32 int_port)

Comment: Thanks for that. I suspected it was that fix, but had no way to separate that from the big roll-up on our system. I tried adding more explicit generic schema, but have not had luck. I imagine that I'll need to develop a complete schema for the XML.

Comment: Hi @kevinfrancis! Could you please post a link to that KB. I'd like to see what it does. Thanks!

Comment: Links to KBs that cause the issue (verified)...
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4565635/kb4565635 and 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4565588/kb4565588

Comment: Adding that code to each top-level CLR object was the solution. Thanks so much for that!